# Vscode Extension - Vectordb LanceDBError: LanceError(IO): Read-only file system (os error 30)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vscode-extensions, vector-database

Hey fellow developers,

Facing the following error when trying to connect to a Local database using the [Typescript Vectorb package](https://github.com/lancedb/lancedb?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start) inside vscode extension development.

```
LanceDBError: LanceError(IO): Read-only file system (os error 30),
 /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/lance-io-0.9.12/src/object_store.rs:315:13.
```

**Code I am trying to Execute**

```
import lancedb, {connect} from 'vectordb';

let db: lancedb.Connection;
let indexTable: lancedb.Table;

export async function connectDatabase() {
    console.log("Trying to connect to VectorDB")
    db = await connect('localdb/data')
    console.log("Connected to VectorDB");
}
```

Steps I've followed

1. Used the example code from the [Documentation](https://github.com/lancedb/lancedb?tab=readme-ov-file#quick-start)
2. The same has worked for connecting to DB and inserting data in a standalone .ts file.
3. However it fails when the same code is used in the Vscode Extension Development environment with the error shared earlier.

What I have already tried?

1. Tried opening Vscode as Admin by executing `sudo code` - Still the same issue
2. Creating Files isn't an issue inside Vscode Extension, I have already tried another database `vectra` which was creating files as part of vscode extension code.
3. `chmod -R 777 /Users/my/code/folder`

How can I fix this?